# What is it that makes I närvarande parter a polonaise?

Tags: theory, sheet-music

Bellman's I närvarande parter is a polonaise. What is it that makes it a polonaise?

[image]

In this video (at 1:31):

it is explained that a polonaise should be based on a specific rhythm, ie one quaver, two semiquavers and four quavers, either in the accompaniment or in the melody.
I närvarande parter seem to not include this rhythm in either the melody or accompaniment. The person in the video could be wrong but I do not know.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, statements that such and such folk dance should be based on such and such musical feature should always be taken with a grain of salt. Folk dances are first of all *dances*. If dancers find that they can nicely dance polonäs on a tune, then it is a polonaise. (It could simultaneously also be a different kind of dance; in practice habits and then tradition establish what's the “proper” interpretation.)

Next, every sheet music of folk music should be read with some leeway, especially when it comes to rhythm. This particular one, *knowing that it is a polonaise*, I would play/sing not like what's written but more like this, bringing out in particular the typical semiquaver before beat two:

```
X:1
L:1/8
M:3/4
K:em
%%score T1
V:T1           clef=treble
V:B           clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] E3/2F/2 G2 FE | F2         B,^C ^DB, | E^D       EF    G^A  | B z/2B,/2 B,2
[V:B]  E,,6           | B,,,3/2 B,,/2 B,,2 A,,2 | G,,3/2F,,/2 G,,^D,, E,,C,, | B,,,2 B,,
```

...and more smaller variations, concerning the length of the beats, exact phrasing and small ornaments (can be as subtle as breathing in a particular way).

Without all that... well, then it would indeed not be possible to infer that this is a polonaise. One could take certain clues, for example in the way there are several scale runs leading up to beat one, but without the characteristic (accelerating?) way these are played in a polonaise it would hardly be conclusive.

In short, what makes Närvarande Parter a polonaise it's that it's played as a polonaise.

Comment: "Next, every sheet music of folk music" Are you saying that Bellman is folk music? If so, how do you define the term folk music? It seems that you don't use folk music as a synonym to traditional music as Bellman is never really considerrd to be that.

Comment: “Folk” is rather besides the point, and whether Bellman himself wrote folk music certainly is. I would say yes, but the point also holds with a composer like Bach who most scholars would probably not call a folk composer. But still, in a piece he labelled as e.g. a sarabande, it's useess to look in the score for reasons why it is a sarabande, instead the correct question to ask is _given that it is a sarabande_, how is it supposed to be played? Even if these composers didn't write folk music themselves, they definitely still based their works on dance rhythms, and labelled them accordingly.

Comment: But at stackexchange we should use correct terminology

Comment: If there is such a thing. Sure. But what's your beef? _Polonaise is a folk dance_, that much should be fairly uncontroversial.

Comment: Polonaise was also danced at the courts.  Folk isn't exactly refering to the courts

Comment: Are you suggesting that polonaise is something fundamentally different depending on whether it's danced by aristocrats or common people? – I mean, no doubt there were differences in the details, but again I don't see how that affects the question.

Comment: All I am saying is that when people use terms they should define them. Folk can refer to lower class people. I think it comes from Johann Gottfried von Herder.

Comment: [Good luck with that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica). Well, I agree that terms that are important for an argument should be defined, but “folk” is not important for the one I'm making here.